# What is a smart way to fill up white space on a profile page (audio streaming platform)

Tags: website-design, design, profile

I have a pretty simple profile page on my website which already contains some elements: the banner, profile picture, about section, timeline, suggested users panel and some various other little things. However, there is a *fairly* large unwanted white space (roughly 200 pixels) on the left side of the timeline.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fill up this space as most of what's available (as far as posts and user info go) is already placed on the page. Someone suggested adding a user gallery, and although it's somewhat a good idea, the website is an audio streaming platform - not an image sharing one.

[image: Image of profile page]

What are some suggestions? Every idea is welcome :)

Comment: Don't add stuff in just for the sake of it. If the layout doesn't work so well for the content you know you need on here then change the layout. Less is more.

Comment: Swap the right sidebar to the left and expand the main content to take up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 1):

If at the moment the product has no plans or iteration of development for the next functionalities, you can move the middle section more to the left and in the future develop functionalities depending on the user's needs

**Spotify** used this space to present main menu

The **Stackexchange** right column contains links to the album of topics
of interest to users

Ideas:

- proposed music
- what your friends listened to
- playback history
- proposed friends

Answer (score 1):

I would choose something dynamic like a social network feed in a column:

[image]

Image source [imgerton.pw/jquery-social-feed-plugin](http://imgerton.pw/jquery-social-feed-plugin.html)